# Enabling an output port in stm32f103c8t6 Blue Pill

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I'm trying to enable the PC13 in the Blue Pill (stm32f103c8t6) which is connected to an LED, not sure if it is active low or active high so i tried both still doesn't work.
`RCC->APB2ENR |= 0x10;`
is used for enabling the clock in Port C.
[image]



`GPIOC->CRH = (GPIOC->CRH & 0xFF0FFFFF) | 0x00100000;`
is used to configure the port C to be in Output mode and Push-Pull.
[image] 



`GPIOC->ODR &= !(1<<13);` is used to drive the C13 pin to LOW.
The whole code:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"

int main(){
    RCC->APB2ENR |= 0x10;
    GPIOC->CRH = (GPIOC->CRH & 0xFF0FFFFF) | 0x00100000;  
    while(1) {
        GPIOC->ODR = ~(1<<13);//if it is Active Low
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) __asm__("nop");
        GPIOC->ODR |= 1<<13; //if it is Active High
        for (int i = 0; i <  500000; ++i) __asm__("nop");
    }

}
```

Edit : 
After some investigation, i discovered that the code is working perfectly if run a debugging session, could it be a software problem? or the code for debugging sets things i didn't ? and as i said, I'm using uVision to compile and flash.

Comment: What HAL or SPL are you using? Are there any functions inside of `stm32f10x.h` which do something to the GPIO?

Comment: `!` is the logical negation operator and sets the result to either 1 or 0. Use the bitwise NOT operator instead, namely `~`.

Comment: @Coddo ,  yeah, right  i dont know how i missed that lol, i edit the code in the question. but it's still the same problem.

Comment: @Tarick Welling , i'm not sure, my code is loaded in 0x08000370, and there are a plenty of instructions before it so i guess there is some functions executed before my code. I'm using uVision to compile and flash.

Comment: After some investigation, i discovered that the code is working perfectly if run a debugging session, could it be a software problem? or the code for debugging sets things i didn't ? and as i said, I'm using uVision to compile and flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Keil as you've said in your comments than it is quite certain that you are using the ST HAL.
As such you should use it.

Use this to enable the GPIOC clock

```
__GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
```

<strike>It also sounds like you haven't enabled another clock. I can't figure out at this time which one it is but  it is probably one high up in the chain. (This probably happens because you enabled the clock using `APB2ENR` instead of the macro)</strike>

Another solution to figure it out would be to use [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) it is a multiplatform tool proved by ST to create base initialized projects for several IDEs.

Download and run it, create a project for your MCU, add the pin you want to drive as an output and generate a Keil project which should compile and run. If it works you can then reverse engineer the steps that STM32CubeMX took to create working code.

---

Your underlying problem is that you haven't enabled `reset and run` in the configuration. As such after programming the board needs to be reset before the newly flashed code will run. Starting the debugger does this.

[image: configuration window with reset and run]

This configuration is found inside the utilities->settings menu. (ignore the red marker, I couldn't capture the image myself and as such got it from the internet)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the STM32CubeMX, it was very helpful. I also realized the pressing the reset button in the blue pill solved the problem.

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE, silly me, that's the problem. you flashed your code, but didn't enable reset upon flash in the flasher settings in keil, so it doesn't reset your board after flashing and does this reset during the start of a debugging session

Answer (score 0):

If you use "volatile" before "int", it will work